# Trouble with simple jQuery calculator on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, calc

I'm trying to make simple calc on jQuery that will calculate total price depending on entered and checked values in input fields. Here is my simplified piece of code but it not works. Where I've made mistake. Thanks.
Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unf21wak/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    var totalextras = 0;
    var rmnumber = 0;
    var bmnumber = 0;

    $('.extras').click(function(){        
        $('.extras:checked').each(function(){
            totalextras += parseInt($(this).val());            
        });
    });

    $('#rm').on('change',function(){
        rmnumber = parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $('#rm').on('change',function(){
        bmnumber = parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    total = totalextras + rmnumber + bmnumber;
    $('#total').text(total);
});
```

```html
<input type='number' id='rm'>
<input type='number' id='bm'><br>
<div class='extra'>
    <label>first</label>
    <input class='extras' type='checkbox' value='100'>
    <label>second</label>
    <input class='extras' type='checkbox'value='500'>
    <label>therd</label>
    <input class='extras' type='checkbox'value='1000'>
    <label>forth</label>
    <input class='extras' type='checkbox'value='1200'>
</div>
<p id='total'>0</p>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. *It doesn't work* isn't sufficient to diagnose your problem. You should explicitly post any errors from your JS console here to aid with answering your question.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what your calculator is even supposed to do. Please provide an *accurate* and *full* description of your problem so we can properly diagnose it.

Comment: The problem is that you aren't updating #total with every change. There also other syntax errors that are causing issues. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Comment: Don't know what do you want, but the jsfiddle below is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/unf21wak/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the total every time an input changes. Your code can also be shrunk down to just a few lines.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var total = 0;

  $('input').on('change', function () {
    total = 0; // Reset the total every time an input changes

    // Check the value of each checkbox
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    // Check the value of each number field
    $('input[type="number"]').each(function () {
      total += $(this).val() ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
    });

    $('#total').text(total);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huwmju01/4/

**Edit:** Updated to reflect Duncan Tidd's suggestion of resetting the number field values to avoid NaN output. Also shortened the whole thing by iterating over each number field type like we do with the checkboxes.

Comment: Nice. I would suggest the OP set an initial value on #rm & #bm to avoid a NaN if either of those inputs are not required.

Comment: Definitely! Great suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I noticed some **logic mistakes** in your code (and fixed them for you as well):

- You are missing a `.` on your `$('.extras:checked')` selector. (EDIT: Only on the Fiddle you provided, the post has already been corrected)
- You are setting an onChange event handler for `$('#rm')` twice, I think you meant `$('#bm')` on the second one.

Now, aside from those mistakes, **here is why your code won't work**:

- Your code `$('#total').text(total);` is only running once, and that is when the page loads. Because you put it directly inside `$(document).ready()`. Instead, you need to put it inside both `on('change')`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total;
    var totalextras=0;
    var rmnumber, bmnumber;

    $('.extras').click(function(){
        $('.extras:checked').each(function(){
            // Change to "+=" if you want the number to keep increasing
            totalextras = parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        // Bonus: If you want to re-calculate when checkbox clicked
        total = totalextras + (rmnumber + bmnumber);
        $('#total').text(total);
    });

    $('#rm').on('change',function(){
        rmnumber = parseInt($(this).val());
        total = totalextras + (rmnumber + bmnumber);
        $('#total').text(total);
    });

    $('#bm').on('change',function(){
        bmnumber = parseInt($(this).val());
        total = totalextras + rmnumber + bmnumber;
        $('#total').text(total);
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unf21wak/6/